# List available sub-resources for provider resource type

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rest-api

I'm attempting to gather a full JSON representation of my Azure resources in a given subscription, but can't figure out how I enumerate the available sub-resources for a given resource type.

For example, I can get the Microsoft.Web/sites/{name} resource, but nothing in that response tells me that Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/config exists. Neither can I find any reference to the /config resource in the Provider object.

Azure Resource Explorer seems to be enumerating them dynamically with very little performance overhead, so I believe it's possible to do this. I just can't figure out how. Examples from NodeJS using the azure-arm-resource nom package:

```
// Returns a data structure, but nothing about subtypes.
let p = client.providers.get("Microsoft.Web");
```

```
// Contains the resource, but not the resources subtypes (e.g. config/appsettings
let r = client.resources.getById(resourceId, apiVersion);
```

I'm looking for something in the APIs that will give me an array of subtypes; in the case of Microsoft.Web/sites, that would be something like ["config", "containerlogs", "diagnostics"...] etc.

Comment: Does it need to work in a NodeJS project?

Comment: Ideally. My project is in Node and Typescript at the moment. Having said that, if you can answer how to enumerate the sub resources via REST, .NET, or any other SDK then I should be able to figure it out in Node.

Comment: Would a PowerShell solution be useful?

Comment: Yes, if it gets the properties in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the call you are looking for:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web?api-version=2019-05-10
```

It return something like this:

```
{
    "resourceTypes": [
        {
            "resourceType": "components",
            "locations": [ xxx ],
            "apiVersions": [ yyy ],
        },
        xxx,
        yyy
    ]
}
```

So you need to examine the output of your call more carefully. or just do a plain rest request and parse the output. but in all honesty, `components()` do not change all that much, you might as well hardcode the list.

Comment: That is the current call I’m making. However, I don’t get “sites/config”, “sites/diagnostics” etc returned as resource types. Checked in Resource Explorer, and also checked I’m not forgetting to nextPage or something. Still no dice. Do you see config under Microsoft.Web? While I want to do this for all resources, getting at Microsoft.Web/sites/config is my acid test at the moment.

Comment: config is not a resource type, its just a property of the sites. available resource types are: hostNameBindings, networkConfig, premieraddons, slots, slots/hostNameBindings, slots/networkConfig

Comment: Understood. Whether we call them resource types, sub types, or properties: how do I get a list of them?

Comment: well, if those are resource types - that api call exposes them. if they are properties - retrieve the object and check (you cannot really get a list of properties, you can check api definition, but it might not list all of the properties). property =! resourceType. resource type is a resource that depends on the parent resource. property - is simply a property of a resource, like its name

Comment: I understand this. I want to programatically get these properties. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use the Swagger REST API specs - https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs